# Magento Cart Rule: discount increases with number of items in the cart from the same category

Tags: cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I want to make a cart rule where if you put:

- 1 item in cart you get 20% off
- 2 items in cart you get 30% off the whole cart
- 3 or more items in the cart you get 40% off the whole cart

All items are from the same category.

I can't seem to find any rule that would make the discount increase this way based on the number of items in cart and that it stops at 40%. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You'll have to apply custom discount.

Comment: create different rule for different item count.